# How to fix "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"?

Tags: python, pandas, math

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from astropy.io import fits
import math

datos = fits.open('gal_line_dr7_v5_2.fit')
dat = datos[1].data

ox = datos[1].data['OIII_5007_CONT']
ni = datos[1].data['NII_6548_CONT']
ha = datos[1].data['H_alpha_CONT']
hb = datos[1].data['H_beta_CONT']

rx = math.log10(ni) - math.log10(ha)
ry = math.log10(ox) - mathlog10(hb)
```

I want rx values but I have this error: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

I can't use numpy because it plots me a wrong graphic. So how can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Also need more info on `ox`, `ni`, `ha`, and `hb`.
Are they single values or are they each numpy arrays?  If they are all arrays of the same length then the solution seems straightforward.

Comment: Yes, they are of the same length and are array, too